# Accessing return value of function passed directly into another in Python

Tags: python, pygtk

I'm testing out a simple sample PyGTK application based on the code in another SO question: [How to set default button in PyGTK?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1114568/how-to-set-default-button-in-pygtk).

However, I'm trying to figure out how to access the value that the run() function returns. I know that it is passed into button.connect() and the other arguments are passed to run() when it is called, but since the function is called latter, I don't know how to access the return value.

```
def foo():
    def run(button, window, entry):
        try: snooze_time = int(entry.get_text())
        except ValueError: snooze_time = 5

        snooze_confirm_message = 'Snoozing for ' + str(snooze_time) + ' minutes'

        dialog = gtk.MessageDialog(window, gtk.DIALOG_MODAL, gtk.MESSAGE_INFO, gtk.BUTTONS_OK, snooze_confirm_message)
        dialog.run()
        dialog.destroy()
        return snooze_time

    snooze_time = None #Defaults to None
    window = gtk.Window()
    window.connect("destroy", gtk.main_quit)

    vbox = gtk.VBox(spacing = 40)
    snooze_time_entry = gtk.Entry()
    vbox.pack_start(snooze_time_entry)

    button = gtk.Button(stock = gtk.STOCK_SAVE)

    #Here the function is being passed to the button, though it is not called until later.
    button.connect("clicked", run, window, snooze_time_entry)
    button.set_flags(gtk.CAN_DEFAULT)
    window.set_default(button)
    vbox.pack_start(button)

    window.add(vbox)
    window.show_all()
    gtk.main()

    print("the result is " + str(snooze_time))
```

If there is a workaround that is more idiomatic with PyGTK, it'd be useful here, though I'd also be interested in knowing a more general, Python approach to this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use class. Something like this (this is not complete code):

```
class Demo:
    def __init__(self):
       self.__snooze_time = None
       self.window = gtk.Window()
       self.window.connect("destroy", gtk.main_quit)
       self.button = gtk.Button(stock = gtk.STOCK_SAVE)

       self.button.connect("clicked", self.run, window, snooze_time_entry)
    def run(self, widget, event, data):
       try: 
          self.__snooze_time = int(data.get_text()) 
       except ValueError: 
          snooze_time = 5
```

Comment: Indeed - you should keep your callback functions as methods in an object, defined in a class - therefore, your function can attributes on the object it belongs to instead of returning values, and any code in or out said object can read that attribute.